# Trying to toggle a form using querySelector and it just isn't budging

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

I was trying to toggle a modal for my register and login tabs on a website I'm working on, but the final part turning it from hidden to visible on the website I was using a little javascript to add an "active" class to the forms making it so they then appear and whatnot... help :)

code:

CSS:

```
.login-form{
color: white;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 37.5%;
transform: transform(-50%,-50%);
background: black;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 2);
visibility: hidden;
transform: .2s;
```

}

```
.login-form.active{
top: 50%;
transition: .2s;
visibility: visible;
```

}

```
.container-fluid.active{
filter: blur(20px);
transition: .2s;
pointer-events: none;
```

}

HTML:
Form -

```
<div class="login-form">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="closeBTN" onclick="loginToggle()">&times;</div>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <form action="loginConfig.php">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Navbar portion:

```
<div class="login">
                <ul>
                    <li onclick="registerToggle()">Registar-se</li>
                    <li onclick="loginToggle()">Login</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
  function loginToggle() {
        var container = document.querySelector('.container-fluid');
        container.classlist.add('active');
        var popup = document.querySelector('.login-form');
        popup.classlist.add('active');
    }
```

Comment: Is that all the code? Not a single element has a class called `.container-fluid` so I don't see how that could do anything. I assume the code does not reach the section adding the class to popup, because of the Typeerror on 2nd line of loginToggle function (Trying to access property .classlist of null)

Comment: The property name is `classList` not `classlist`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Syntax adjustments I suggest: use `let` instead of `var` for variables that change, `const` instead of `var` for variables that stay the same.
Then place all variables at the top of your function, to keep them sorted. (in your case all would be `const`)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski the .container-fluid is the bootstrap div that encapsulates the whole HTML code

Comment: @Frizzant thank you <3 i'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your problem is that you don't respect the camel case of Java Script. You have to use it as "classList" instead of "classlist".

Also you don't have any element having ".container-fluid" in your code so that will trigger an error as well.
Consider removing that line and change from classlist to classList and give it a try:

```js
  function loginToggle() {
        //var container = document.querySelector('.container-fluid');
        //container.classList.add('active');
        var popup = document.querySelector('.login-form');
        popup.classList.add('active');
    }
```

```css
.login-form{
color: white;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 37.5%;
transform: transform(-50%,-50%);
background: black;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 2);
display:none;
transform: .2s;
}

.login-form.active{
top: 50%;
transition: .2s;
visibility: visible;
}

.container-fluid.active{
filter: blur(20px);
transition: .2s;
pointer-events: none;
}
.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-form">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="closeBTN" onclick="loginToggle()">&times;</div>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <form action="loginConfig.php">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="login">
                <ul>
                    <li onclick="registerToggle()">Registar-se</li>
                    <li onclick="loginToggle()">Login</li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: fixing the classList error (Jesus I'm dumb for not realizing it wasn't typed correctly sorry for that) does make it popup but if I do click the "&times;" div it doesn't disappear simply added another function to remove the "active" classList and that did it :) thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, somehow someone considered my answer as bad.